# Receiving a 404 error on my android project when sending a request using phone data but receiving a good response when connected to wifi

Tags: android, android-studio, http-status-code-404, okhttp

Keep in mind that all my permissions are ok and its not a library issue since i have tried using urlConnection and volley but still getting the same error.Its a simple json post to a cloud hosted API 
    And I should also mention that the problem only seems to occur on different phones,also upon execution am getting the IOException with a 404 response status.
Here is my code, kindly assist

```
 @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO: attempt authentication against a network service.
            Boolean respValue = false;

            try {

            MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
                Map<String, String> url_params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                url_params.put("appid", "123456");
                url_params.put("apppass", "1234567");
                url_params.put("username",mEmail);
                url_params.put("userpassword",mPassword);
                url_params.put("appserviceid","12345");
                JSONObject parameter = new JSONObject(url_params);

                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, parameter.toString());

                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(getResources().getString(R.string.API_login))
                        .post(body)
                        .addHeader("content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
                        .build();

                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();


                if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
                } else {
                    Log.i("Server_Response", response.body().string());

                    String respd = (client.newCall(request).execute()).body().string();

                    JSONObject json_obj = new JSONObject(respd);
                    String state = json_obj.getString("state");
                    Response = Integer.valueOf(state);
                    MESSAGE = json_obj.getString("msg");

                    Log.i("State", state);
                    Log.i("Msg", MESSAGE);
                    respValue = true;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("responseError", "Error");
                respValue = false;
            }

            return respValue;
        }
```

Comment: Check your URL if it's correct. First test your web service if it's working before you implement in Android

Comment: The URL is okay @Sharj because when I turn off  data on my phone and connect to wifi its able to send the request without any issues

Comment: Try using web browser in your phone to access that URL or that web server and check the result

Comment: I have installed a ping tool on my phone and its pinging fine @BNK

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone feedback but i finally figured out the issue, it has something to do with the connectivity settings you get from your mobile network operator, which in my case i just requested for new settings and everything worked fine.

Comment: Can you tell us what was those setting? We are having the same problem

Comment: Request for new internet connection settings from your mobile operator, there is usually a short code for such services